# Ant Design Chart is showing future data that doesn't exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a problem with the Ant Design Charts library. I use it because in my knowledge it is good to use with react.js and typescript.

I made a component in React.js, called LineChart, which assembles the chart, and another called LineBlock, which processes the data to assemble the chart.

There are no help forums for those using AntD for graphics, so I'm looking for help here.

It turns out that my data comes with a date to create a common line graph, however, in my time zone of -3 hours, it ends up that the graph created is made with the time zone 0 hours, that is, the graph is built and only Then I adjust the date to appear in the caption with my ideal time zone. I tried to do some processing before inserting the data into the graph, but if successful, it didn't show any differences.

```
export default function LineChart({
  data = [],
  loading,
  config,
  type = 'line',
  size,
}: LineChartProps) {
  const { actualLanguage } = useActualLanguage();
  const { ui } = useSettings();
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const isSmall = useMemo(() => size < 250, [size]);

  const legend = useMemo(
    () => ({
      itemName: {
        formatter: (category: string) => category.split('|')[0],
        style: {
          fill: ui?.['color-text-normal'],
        },
      },
      offsetY: isSmall ? 0 : -8,
      pageNavigator: {
        marker: {
          style: {
            fill: ui?.['color-text-normal'],
            inactiveFill: ui?.['color-bg-page'],
            size: 9,
          },
        },
        text: {
          style: {
            fontSize: 11,
          },
        },
      },
    }),
    [isSmall, ui],
  );

  const { min, max } = useMemo(() => {
    if (data.length === 0) return { min: 0, max: 0 };
    const map = data
      .map((datum: Data) => [
        Number((0.9 * (datum.value as number)).toFixed(2)),
        Number((1.05 * (datum.value as number)).toFixed(2)),
      ])
      .flat();

    return {
      min: Math.min(...map),
      max: Math.max(...map),
    };
  }, [data]);

  const minDecimals = useMemo(() => {
    let min = 2;
    data.forEach((datum: Data) => {
      if (datum.category) {
        const decimal = Number((datum.category as string).split('|')[4]);
        if (decimal < min) {
          min = decimal;
        }
      }
    });
    return min;
  }, [data]);

  const defaultConfig: LineConfig = {
    data,
    xField: 'time',
    yField: 'value',
    color: config.color
      ? config.color
      : data.map((datum: Data) => (datum.category as string).split('|')[2]),
    point: {
      size: 2.5,
    },
    xAxis: {
      max: Math.max(
        ...data.map((item) => new Date(item.time as string).getTime()),
      ),

      type: 'time',
      label: {
        style: {
          fontSize: isSmall ? 8 : 12,
          fill: ui?.['color-text-normal'],
        },
      },
    },
    yAxis: {
      label: {
        formatter: (value) => Number(value).toFixed(minDecimals),
        style: {
          fontSize: isSmall ? 8 : 12,
          fill: ui?.['color-text-normal'],
        },
      },
      minLimit: min,
      maxLimit: max,
      nice: true,
    },
    legend: isSmall ? false : legend,
    lineStyle: function (datum) {
      if (datum.category.split('|')[1] == 'dashed') {
        return {
          lineDash: [1, 5],
        };
      }
    },
    meta: {
      time: {
        formatter: (value) =>
          new Date(value)
            .toLocaleString(actualLanguage, {
              month: 'numeric',
              day: 'numeric',
              hour: 'numeric',
              minute: 'numeric',
              hour12: false,
            })
            .replaceAll(',', ' '),
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: (datum) => {
        const name = datum.category.split('|')[0];
        const value = datum.value;
        return {
          name: name,
          value:
            value.toFixed(Number(datum.category.split('|')[4])) +
            datum.category.split('|')[3],
        };
      },
    },
    smooth: false,
    stepType: undefined,
  };

  const mergedConfig = { ...defaultConfig, ...config };

  if (type === 'spline') {
    mergedConfig.smooth = true;
  }

  if (data[0] && typeof data[0].category === 'string') {
    if (data[0].category.split('|')[1] === LineTypes.spline) {
      mergedConfig.smooth = true;
    }
    if (data[0].category.split('|')[1] === LineTypes.step) {
      mergedConfig.stepType = 'hvh';
    }
  }

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }
  return data.length === 0 ? (
    <div className="flex gap-4 items-center justify-center w-full h-full text-wsm-normal text-xl">
      <Prohibit weight="bold" className="text-wsm-primary" />
      <span>{t('no_data')}</span>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Line {...mergedConfig} className="w-full h-full" />
  );
}
```

Example data:

```
[
    {
        "time": "2024-01-17T10:20:00.000Z",
        "value": 855,
        "category": "Value|line|#bb5050||0"
    },
    {
        "time": "2024-01-17T10:30:00.000Z",
        "value": 855,
        "category": "Value|line|#bb5050||0"
    }
]
```

How show in screen:

[image]

All I need is for that space at the end of the graph where there are no points to be there.

Comment: The issue is because of timezone difference. You need to convert the time data to desired timezone before rendering the chart.